# How to get return value from and SQL Stored Procedure Run Using Perl?

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure in MS SQL using perl 
The return value is an integer (0 = if ok, and some negative values if it exited early at certain points)
while the code runs the SP - it doesn't give me the return value at all.

my code:

```
use dbd::odbc;
#...
$dbh->do("use XXX"); #Name of the DB
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "
   DECLARE \@return_value int

   EXEC \@return_value = [dbo].[test1] 
        \@BeginDate = '11/11/2011',
        \@EndDate = '11/11/2011'

   select  \@return_value 

");

$sth->execute( );

#### AFTER THIS I TRIED:

while ( @dbrow = $sth->fetchrow_array(  ) ) {
   $return_value = @dbrow[0]
}

#### i also tried:

my $return_value = $sth->fetchrow_array(  )

#### both get nothing.
```

When I use regular `SELECT` queries, both of the above work.

Comment: also, the above procedure, if ran in SQL Server Management Studio gives me a correct return value

Comment: From your code, it is pretty clear you don't have warnings enabled.  Please do enable them with `use warnings;`

Comment: Are you sure things are even executing? You're not checking the return values of any of your DB or statement handle method calls.

Comment: Try executing the procedure in SQL server and make sure it returns atleast one record

Comment: yes i am sure things are executing! the procedure runs fine and  bothin sql studio AND in perl. all that needs to be done is being done! BUT!!! there is no return result in perl.

Comment: You should only need 'use DBI;', not 'use dbd::odbc;' which is wrong anyway (The library is 'DBD::ODBC'. Perl is case-sensitive although your file system may not be, introducing subtle bugs).

Comment: Also, use { RaiseError => 1 } in the connect.

Comment: Have you enabled strict and warnings yet?

Answer (score 1):

What *does* it return?  Try this:

```
while ( @dbrow = $sth->fetchrow_array(  ) ) {
    use Data::Dumper;
    $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
    print Dumper( { "got row" => \@dbrow } );
}
```

Comment: tried the above. nothing.
if i print "MY VALUE IS $return_value" i will get MY VALUE IS
if i try with @dbrow - same thing. Basically its not even going 
into the while loop! meaning the SP is not returning anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

- Try executing the procedure in SQL server and make sure it returns
  atleast one record
- Check the return value of the execute statement, print error if it is not successful

  $sth->execute() or die "Couldn't execute: " . $sth->errstr;
- Check the number of rows from sth

  if ($sth->rows == 0) {print "Zero records"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but can you try this one.

```
while ( $row_ref = $sth->fetch_arrayref() ) {
    my $return_value = $row_ref->[0];
    print $return_value;
}
```